# Regex selecting text between two known words

Tags: regex, variables

I have pattern
TABLE *some_table* LARGE READ_ONLY LOTS_OF_OTHER_WORDS {

I want to select out
LARGE READ_ONLY LOTS_OF_OTHER_WORDS

I want to strip out all the words after some_table, where some_table is a different table name every time.
I tried (?<=TABLE\s(.*?)\s).* but the (.*?) doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

is this it?

```
TABLE \w+ (.*)
```

http://regexr.com?30ncp

Answer (score 0):

- Is there always a curly bracket after the words that you want to strip out ?
- Is the some_table name always a one word name ?

If so, I'd use:

```
TABLE\s?(\s*[^{]*?){
```

Then you need to replace the match in the first group.

EDIT:I forgot about the table name that should not be part of the match - updated regex:

```
TABLE\s*?\w+\s?([^{]*?){
```

Explanation:
- find the string TABLE
- match the first word (and allow whitespaces before and after it) `\s*?\w+\s?`
- the group: match everything that's not a curly bracket `([^{]*?)`
- match the bracket

Comment: Interesting, in theory I think this one should work but for some reason its grabbing the whole line. Thanks for this one though!

Comment: @user1347047 - what is the whole line and what was expected?